# ADF foreach on JSON Object

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have a json configuration file which is of type json that has a total of two objects something similar to this.

[
{
"Student": A
"Class" : 8
"Homework: : {
"type": "complete"
}
},
{
"Student": B
"Class" : 9
"Homework: : {
"type": "Incomplete"
}
}
]

My pipeline needs to go through this configuration file and loop through each object and extract student A and His class and Homework type and put them in seperate variables to feed a URL using the web activity.

I tried using a look up activity in the pipeline and then add a foreach loop to go through two objects and within the foreach activity place a web task but foreach loop isnt happy with the object type, it wants a string or an array.

Anyone has any suggestions how to go about looping and parsing a JSON object to extract info and use that info to do a web activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the sample Json object in lookup activity and gave that json as an input to for-each activity. Below are the steps.

**Sample Json:**

```json
 [
        {
            "Student": "A",
            "Class": 8,
            "Homework": {
                "type": "complete"
            }
        },
        {
            "Student": "B",
            "Class": 9,
            "Homework": {
                "type": "Incomplete"
            }
        }
    ]
```

- Lookup activity is taken, and input Json is given as source dataset. First row only option is unchecked.

[image]

- Then for-each activity is taken and in settings, value for Items is given as `@activity('lookup1').output.value`.

[image]

- In order to access the value of Student, Class, Homework type from Json, you can give the values as `@item().Student`, `@item().Class`, and `@item().Homework.type` respectively inside foreach activity.

Comment: Super helpful thanks Aswin.  
So for the Item().Homework I have to send in the entire Object to the web activity's body.  When I add only Item().Homework only to assign to the set variable, it tells me that it only supports String.

Comment: Yes, Variable doesn't support object type. You can convert the value to string using the expression `@string(item().Homework)`. You can also try sending the value `@item().Homework` in body of web activity, instead of storing it in variable and using there.

Comment: Yes, thank you soo much. I see your helping me with another issue too. Thank you much.